# printf() with no arguments in C compiles fine. how?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior

I tried the below c program & I expected to get compile time error, but why compiler isn't giving any error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why output is compiler dependent?
Here is the output on various compilers

Output on Orwell Dev C++ IDE (uses gcc 4.8.1) : 0

Output on Visual C++ provided by Visual Studio 2010 : 0

CodeBlocks IDE (uses gcc 4.7.1) : garbage value

Online compiler ideone.com : garbage value

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: You can make your compiler tell you about that, by enabling warnings. Though this program compiles it will search for a matching integer argument causing undefined behavior.

Comment: That is the beauty of **Undefined Behaviour** :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program will compile fine, as `printf()` is a variadic function and the matching check of the number of format specifiers with supplied argument is not performed by default.

At runtime, your program exhibits [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as there in no argument supplied which has to be printed using the supplied format specifier.

As per chapter 7.19.6.1, `c99` standard, (from `fprintf()`)

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.

If you compile using `-Wformat` flag in `gcc`, your compiler will produce the warning for the mismatch.

Comment: You might also mention the more general `gcc -Wall` and `clang -Weverything` options.

Answer (score 7):

Because of how C variadic arguments work, the compiler cannot track their correct usage. It is still (syntactically) legal to provide less, or more, parameters that the function needs to work, although this generally ends up as undefined behavior when looking at the standard.

The declaration of `printf` looks like this:

```
int printf(const char*, ...);
```

The compiler only sees `...`, and knows that there may be zero or more additional arguments that the function may or may not use. The called function **does not know** how many arguments it is passed; it can, at best, *assume* that it was passed all the information it needs and nothing more.

Contrast this with other languages, like C#:

```
void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arguments);
```

Here, the method knows exactly how many additional arguments is was passed (doing `arguments.Length`).

In C, variadic functions and especially `printf` are a frequent cause of security vulnerabilities. `Printf` ends up reading raw bytes from the stack, which may leak important details about your application and its security environment.

For this reason, Clang and GCC support a special extension to validate `printf` formats. If you use an invalid format string, you'll get a warning (not an error).

```
code.c:4:11: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
    printf("%d\n");
           ~~^
```

Answer (score 4):

This is simply [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you do not provide the sufficient arguments to `printf`, which mean the behavior is unpredictable. From the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which also covers `printf` for this case:

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Since `printf` is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) there is no matching of arguments to the function declaration. So the compiler needs to support support format string checking which is covered by [-Wformat flag in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> Check calls to printf and scanf, etc., to make sure that the arguments supplied have types appropriate to the format string specified, and that the conversions specified in the format string make sense. This includes standard functions, and others specified by format attributes (see Function Attributes), [...]

Enabling sufficient compiler warnings is important, for this code `gcc` using the `-Wall` flag tells us (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65a9999b1d02f72d)*):

```
 warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
 printf("%d\n");
 ^
```

Answer (score 3):

This compiles well. Because it matches the printf() prototype which is

```
printf(const char *,...);
```

During run-time the call

```
printf("%d\n");
```

Tries to fetch the value from second argument and since you have not passed anything it might get some garbage value and print it out so the behavior is undefined here.

Answer (score 2):

In general diagnostic messages (you may think of them like compilation errors) are not guaranteed for [undefined behaviors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (like lack of sufficient arguments for `printf` function call as in your case), that are not counted as syntax rule or constraint violations.

> #### C11 (N1570) §5.1.1.3/p1 *Diagnostics*:
>
> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of **any syntax rule or constraint**, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.
>   Diagnostic messages **need not be produced** in other circumstances.<sup>9)</sup>

In other words your compiler is free to translate such unit, but you should never run it or rely on its behaviour (as it's de facto unpredictable). Moreover your compiler is allowed not to provide any documentation (that is C Standard does not enforce it to do so), like it's required for implementation-defined or locale-specific behaviours.

> #### C11 (N1570) §3.4.3/p2 *undefined behavior*:
>
> NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message).

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking undefined behaviour. That's your problem, not the compiler's, and basically anything is "allowed" to happen.

Of course, virtually every existing compiler should be able to warn you about this particular condition regarding `printf()`, you just have to allow him to (by enabling, and heeding, compiler warnings).

Answer (score 2):

Using `g++` with commandline parameter `-Wall` produces the following diagnostics:

```
g++ -Wall   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main(void)':
main.cpp:17:16: warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d");
                ^
```

That's pretty useful, isn't it?

`gcc/g++` also check if the format specifiers actually match the parameter types. This is really cool for debugging.

Comment: And How does this answer the question?

Comment: The code snippet compiles fine, unless warnings are enabled (cf. comment of @iharob). Checking of variadic parameters seems to be a strength of g++/gcc and is probably not provided by most other compilers.

Comment: Adding `-Werror` will make these warnings fatal and prevent compilation.  A sane precaution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), the additional arguments must be at least as many as the format specifiers in the first argument. This seems to be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

what warnings/messages did you get using your compilers?
i ran this through gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) and got a warning

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d\n");
     ^
```

and running it also "garbage output".
here, the gcc is so clever to parse the format expression and notifies the coder to provide a matching number of arguments.

what i think happens:
the function signature of printf is *independent* from the behaviour of the compiled code. at compile time, all the compiler cares is to check if at least one argument is there and continues. however, the compiled function will first parse the format expression and, dependent on that, read further arguments from the functions' arguments stack. therein it simply expects appropriately put values (int, float etc) and uses them.
so if you dont specify the argument, no place on the function call stack is reserved and printf still reads random memory (in this case at the first location). this also explains the "garbage" output, which will differ each time you call the binary. you can even extend the code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n%d\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and get two *different* garbage numbers :)

then again it will depend on the environment/process/compiler which values will be read. "unspecified behaviour" is what describes this effect best, sometimes zero, sometimes other.

i hope this clarifies your issue!

Answer (score -1):

In the context of printf() and fprintf(), as per C standard C11 clause 7.21.6.1, "If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined. If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored."