# __FILE__ macro will be concatenated to previous string accidentally in C

Tags: c

This is the simplest example of my question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
        printf("%s:%s\n", "I am in file" __FILE__);
}
```

When I forget to insert a comma before "**__FILE__**" macro, I expect to get a compile error, but just get a warning. So the output will be:

> I am in filetest.c:[C

- 1st string will be : "I am in file" concatenate with **__FILE__** macro
- 2nd string will be undefined

Could someone tell me why it is not a compile error?

Comment: To the people marking this as a duplicate of questions about string concatenation, the question is *not* about the string concatenation but why the compiler doesn't give an error for passing to few arguments to a varargs function.

Comment: As Some programmer dude said: He already got how string concatenation works. OP saids: `2nd string will be undefined` because of `%s:%s`. What he want's to know is why this is not a compiler error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so what should I close this as? brightshine: because you're using a bad compiler (and you didn't disclose which one you're using).

Comment: You say that you _just get a warning_. What warning? `gcc` gives: `warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument`, which seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Who says it has to be closed? Why?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because it is a duplicate?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Of what? Of questions about string-concatenations? But the question *isn't* about that, therefore such questions aren't duplicates. If you find a question about why missing arguments to vararg functions isn't an error, then I'll gladly vote to close this question, but not otherwise.

Comment: The title of the question states that the concatanation is "accidental". The duplicate quenstion makes clear that such concatenations _always_ happen.

Comment: @HansLub: With accidental he wants to express that fact that he might forget the comma: `When I forget to insert a comma before [...]`. I think this is clear to the OP.

Comment: @HansLub The title is a little misleading and should probably be edited. The question itself is IMO quite clear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude a duplicate of "why no error of wrong number of arguments to printf"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I can't find that question on SO. Can you provide a link?

Comment: For example this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28194227/918959 even simpler. Why conflate it with string concatenation.

Comment: The string concatenation is just a reasoning why the error could happen to a careful user, but at the core the question is about "why doesn't compiler give a diagnostic message when too few arguments are provided to printf when the format is known".

Answer (score 5):

While it is possible for the compiler to do it in e.g. `printf` and `scanf` (because it knows about the format-strings for those functions), it can't be generally done for variable-argument functions.

If you create a vararg function, how would the compiler know what number of arguments is the correct? The answer is that it can't. Therefore the C specification doesn't say it has to be an error.

That compilers (some, not all) give warnings for `printf` and `scanf` is just because the creators of the compiler are nice enough to add it. It's not required.