# Printing values, pointers and pointers to values

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   int i;
    int *p;
    p = &i;
    i=5;

    printf("i = %d, p = %P, *p = %d\n",i,p,*p);

    *p=6;
    printf("i = %d, p = %P, *p = %d\n",i,p,*p);

    return 0;
}
```

the output of this code is:

```
i = 5, p = %P, *p = -1009882308
i = 6, p = %P, *p = -1009882308
```

where it should give *p=5 in 1st statement and in 2nd statement *p=6

Comment: first, i'd recommend replacing `%P` with `%p`.  the `P` format specifier does not exist.

Comment: i'm surprised that your compiler didn't give you a warning for having more "objects" than specifiers.  replace the format specifier like i stated above and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28194300/5982321) for knowing why there was no compile errors/warnings.

Comment: @Tau yes my compiler gave warning for %P but if we don't focus on that then also for *p it should return value of i i.e., 5 and then 6

Comment: as i stated above, you're getting a problem with mismatching specifiers and "objects".  the way that your string is formatted, `p` will be printed where `%d` is instead of `%P`.  fix the latter specifier and your code will work.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

In your printf you try to display `p = %P` or `%P` doesn't exist, so the `%`P will be ignored and will be print like a string.

After, when you try to print `*p = %d`, you don't print the variable `*p` but you print `p` because `p` havn't been used by the `%P`.

Correct printf should be:

```
printf("i = %d, *p = %d\n",i,*p);
```

Comment: can you please explain the last line

Comment: In printf  `printf("i = %d, p = %P, *p = %d\n",i,p,*p);` you have one %d, one %P and another %d. And three variables: i, p, *p. So printf will display first the %d with his corresponding variable (i), after printf will ignore the %P (because %P doesn't exits) and finaly printf will print the %d with is corresponding variable (p) because (p) havn't been used by the %P. The last variable (*p) is unused. To make (*p) used you have to delete the variable (p) in your printf.

Comment: "so the %P will be ignored and will be print like a string." --> "%P will be ignored ..." is only one possibility. As `"%P"` is not a specified _print specifier_, the result is _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Answer (score 4):

You have specified the following string as your formatted string to `printf()`:

`i = %d, p = %P, *p = %d`

Then you specify three elements to be printed:

`i, p, *p`

So, `%d` gets replaced with the value stored in `i`, as expected:

`i = 5, p = %P, *p = %d`

All good so far, except for one thing: the format `%P` **does not exist**.  Therefore, it gets skipped as a specifier and is instead printed out.

Then the second `%d` is replaced with the value in `p`, *not* `*p`, since the second `%d` is the next valid specifier, and `p` is the next variable to be used:

`i = 5, p = %P, *p = -1009882308`

Since there are *no more specifiers left to use*, `*p` gets ignored and a warning, or possibly an error, is thrown when compiling.

Congratulations, you just printed the address that `p` points to as an `int`, aka **Undefined Behaviour**.

**So, how do we remedy this?**

Replace `%P` with the actual valid specifier: `%p`.  Now *all* variables and specifiers are used, and your code will run smoothly.

This is what `printf()` should've printed:

`i = 5, p = C3CE6B3C, *p = 5`

**Note:** using `%p` prints the address of `p`, which will be printed as a hexadecimal number.

**EDIT:** As *chux* stated, `%p` requires a corresponding `void*` to work as intended.  Cast `p` to a `(void*)` in the `printf()` statement like so:  `(void*)p`

Comment: Detail: "*p gets ignored and a warning, or possibly an error, is thrown when compiling." --> Extra parameters in a `printf()` are OK.  C is well specified to handle that.  Yet some compile will warn (it is usually a coding mistake) and some compiler options treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: `"%p"` matches a `void*`, `p` is a `int*`.  A mis-match is UB.  Best to use `"%p"` and `(void*)p`.

Comment: noted.  i edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

Your format specifier has a typo, it is not recognized. As a result, you're passing the pointer to be printed as an integer. It should be like this:

```
printf("i = %d, p = %p, *p = %d\n",i,p,*p);
```

Most compliers will issue a warning for your code. If yours doesn't, please check if you can change the settings to be more strict with warnings.

Comment: yes my compiler gave warning for %P but if we don't focus on that then also for *p it should return value of i i.e., 5 and then 6

Comment: Looking at your output, it worked.  You get `i = 5` the first time and `i = 6` the second time.

Comment: @deep_purohit When you messed up the %P, there is no guarantee that printing *p will work as you expect it to. Coding errors can have consequences such that a bug in one place can make code another place do unexpected things, and in this case it has severe consequences.

Comment: but then why *p is working as p only coz the value returned by *p is the address of i

Comment: `%p` expects a pointer, so you need to pass `p`. `%d` expects an integer, so you can pass `i` or `*p`.

Comment: @deep_purohit since `%P` is not a valid format specifier, `p` which is the second argument gets used by `%d`. And printing an address with `%d` is going to give you weird results.

Comment: `"%p"` expects a `void*`, not just any pointer.

Comment: @deep_purohit: Never ignore warnings - this particular warning was relevant to why you're seeing bad output.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the output of the following C code is like this?
>   yes my compiler gave warning for %P but if we don't focus on that then also for *p it should return value of i i.e., 5 and then 6  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628402/why-the-output-of-the-following-c-code-is-like-this#comment92190580_52628402).

The key problem is assuming that code after a warning should behave well.

That warning was a result of using an invalid print specifier `"%P"`.  That leads to *undefined behavior* (UB).  The rest of code no longer has any specified behavior.  Thus "should return value of i i.e., 5 and then 6" is not support by C.  The output could be anything.

---

Use valid print specifiers and matching arguments.

Use `"%p"` to print a `void*`.  To convert `p` to a `void*`, apply a cast.

```
// printf("i = %d, p = %P, *p = %d\n",i,p,*p);
printf("i = %d, p = %p, *p = %d\n", i, (void*)p, *p);
```

Answer (score 0):

`%P` is not a valid conversion specifier, so your second argument `p` is being printed as a decimal integer with `%d`, and `*p` is not being printed at all.

Change both lines to

```
printf("i = %d, p = %p, *p = %d\n",i, (void *)p,*p);
                     ^
                     |
                     +---- note lower case p here
```

and you will get the output you expect.